# I do not understand the syntax of this snippet

Tags: javascript

```js
const createUser = ({ userName, avatar }) => ({
  userName,
  avatar,
  setUserName (userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    return this;
  }
});
console.log(createUser({ userName: 'echo', avatar: 'echo.png' }));
/*
{
  "avatar": "echo.png",
  "userName": "echo",
  "setUserName": [Function : setUserName]
}
*/
```

I was reading about factory function and I stumbled upon this snippets but I do not understand the function expression. I dont know if it is an object or IIFE. and I do not understand why it return the property "setUserName" : [Function setUserName]?

````js
const createUser = ({ userName, avatar }) => ({
  userName,
  avatar,
  setUserName (userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    return this;
  }
});
console.log(createUser({ userName: 'echo', avatar: 'echo.png' }));
/*
{
  "avatar": "echo.png",
  "userName": "echo",
  "setUserName": [Function : setUserName]
}
*/
```js
````

Comment: it's an (simple) arrow function that returns an object - simple in that it's a single statement in the body (surrounded by `()` because that's how you return an object in a simple arrow function), therefore the `return` (after =>) is implied

Comment: Its a function returning an object. It's not an IIFE, as it is not invoked immeadiately. And why exactly does `setUserName" : [Function setUserName]` confuse you? Thats a property containing a function?

Comment: the best way to understand ES6+ code if you are not familiar with it is to run it through something like babel to get the ES5 version

Comment: @jaromanda oh no, thats a bad advice ... That might give useful results for such simple features, but async / await or generators really look awful (cause they are hard to transpile)

Comment: Yeah @JonasWilms - that's true, but still, you do get an insight into what the code is doing

Comment: thanks, now I understand returning object literals from arrow function. However, should not setUserName have colons as it is a property of an object. I mean inside the arrow function body.

Comment: Thats just a [shorthand method name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), for sure you could also just write `setUserName: function(name)` that would do exactly the same.

Comment: I understood the shorthand method name. but should not the result be like:  
setUserName : Function,  
why there is square brackets it seems like an array containing a property and a value.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this we start by removing syntax sugar.
First shorthand object definitions:

```
const createUser = ({ userName, avatar }) => ({
  userName: userName,
  avatar: avatar,
  setUserName: setUserName (userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    return this;
  }
});
```

Next we remove the destruction:

```
const createUser = (data) => ({
  userName: data.userName,
  avatar: data.avatar,
  setUserName: setUserName (userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    return this;
  }
});
```

And last we remove the shorthand return of the arrow function:

```
const createUser = (data) => {
  return {
    userName: data.userName,
    avatar: data.avatar,
    setUserName: setUserName (userName) {
      this.userName = userName;
      return this;
    }
  };
}
```

We could also replace the arrow function by a normal function, but this will slightly change the behaviour (not that it matters in this case):

```
function createUser (data) {
  return {
    userName: data.userName,
    avatar: data.avatar,
    setUserName: setUserName (userName) {
      this.userName = userName;
      return this;
    }
  };
}
```

Now its easy to understand what this is:
This is a function

- getting one parameter, being an object with the properties `userName` and `avatar`
- returning an object containing 3 properties

  - `userName` and `avatar` getting the same value as the passed parameter
  - and `setUserName` being a function that takes a parameter, sets the `userName` property of the object to that parameter, and then returning the object.

So this is neither an object or IIFE. It is a function that returns an object.

On that new object you have a function `setUserName`. So if you use the `createUser` function like this:

```
const myUser = createUser({ userName: 'echo', avatar: 'echo.png' });
```

Then you can do

```
myUser.setUserName('BlaBla');
```

effectively being equivalent to

```
myUser.userName = 'BlaBla';
```

However because it `return this` you can nest it:

```
myUser.setUserName('One').setUserName('Two');
```

Not that this makes sense. But if you would define another function like `setAvatar` it could be useful do

```
myUser.setUserName('One').setAvatar('One.jpg');
```

instead of

```
myUser.userName = 'One';
myUser.avatar = 'One.jpg';
```

Comment: thank your for the elaboration. but still why the console log the property's 'setUserName' value with  square brackets and a Function keyword.

Comment: `console.log` ist not really standarized. It just returns something the browser vendor think will help you. And they just use decided to use that was with square brackets to show the property value is a function and it's name. There is not really a *meaning*

Comment: thanks Lux. that explains the remained question mark.

Answer (score 0):

What Are Arrow Functions?
Arrow functions – also called “fat arrow” functions, from CoffeeScript (a transcompiled language) — are a more concise syntax for writing function expressions. They utilize a new token, =>, that looks like a fat arrow. Arrow functions are anonymous and change the way this binds in functions.

Arrow functions make our code more concise, and simplify function scoping and the this keyword. They are one-line mini functions which work much like Lambdas in other languages like C# or Python. (See also lambdas in JavaScript). By using arrow functions, we avoid having to type the function keyword, return keyword (it’s implicit in arrow functions), and curly brackets.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)